# Canvas on surfaceView flickering

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

I am writing drawing app and use canvas. I created my surfaceView and override onTouch function to track user's finger movement. But when user is drawing surfaceView is flickering. How can i fix it?

This is my drawing code:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event != null)
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && holder != null) {
        thread {
            val canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
            canvas.drawBitmap(brush,
                event.x - brush.width.div(2),
                event.y - brush.height.div(2),
                null)
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
        }.join()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine having a new thread created via the https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html each time the onTouchEvent happens is pretty expensive and would cause some flickering. Instead, I would try having the canvas lock/unlock + bitmap drawing loop in a single thread and tell the thread when the x and y changes from the onTouchEvent.

Comment: I tried to draw on canvas in separate thread but it still flickering :(

Comment: But i find solution - implement View instead of SurfaceView